# Why C++ ofstream is faster than C FILE?

Tags: c++, c

I'm comparing C and C++ file handlers, and I wrote two functions.
C FILE:

```
void CFprintfBuffer() {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("CFprintfBuffer.txt", "w");
  char buffer[1001];
  buffer[999] = '\n';
  buffer[1000] = '\0';

  for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 999; ++i) {
      char ch = rand() % 95 + 32;
      buffer[i] = ch;
    }

    fprintf(file, "%s", buffer);
  }

  fclose(file);
}
```

And C++ ofstream:

```
void CPPOperatorBuffer() {
  std::ofstream file;
  file.open("CPPOperatorBuffer.txt", std::ios::out);
  char buffer[1001];
  buffer[999] = '\n';
  buffer[1000] = '\0';

  for (int n = 0; n != 10000; ++n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 999; ++i) {
      char ch = rand() % 95 + 32;
      buffer[i] = ch;
    }

    file << buffer;
  }

  file.close();
}
```

I expected than first one would be much faster, but actually the second is faster: for ofstream it took 1.54 seconds on average to finish the task, when for C FILE it took 2.02 seconds. Can anyone explain this results? Or maybe I did some mistake in the functions?

Comment: Never measure performance based on console observations. Use performance measurement tools instead.

Comment: questions about performance and runtime need even more details than usual. What compiler? What flags? What hardware? How did you measure? And most importantly: Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: The best comparison would be with `fputs` instead of `fprintf`.

Comment: Why do you use `< 10000` in one of them but `!= 10000` in the other? When comparing things for performance like this, aside from the comments above, you need to be sure not to change things that are unrelated to what you're trying to check. (Although I can't imagine that that particular difference would matter in this specific case.) Also, Ian Abbott's point is very well taken, `fprintf` has to do much more work than `<<`.

Comment: `fprintf` is a pretty complex function whereas `file << buffer` probably ends up performing a `fputs(buffer)`. Replace `fprintf`  witgh `fputs` and see what happens.

Comment: How are the programs compiled?  How are they linked? Is the buffering the same for the files? If you compiled or linked the C version with C++, how do the C and C++ `stdout` streams interact?  And you also haven't established that the `rand()` used in C and C++ is identical, with the same performance characteristics.

Comment: `fprintf` is a heavy call to OS. `std::ofstream` has internal buffer so it will make less calls to OS. I am uncertain of the buffer size though and thus uncertain if that's the reason.